# Как вызвать функцию по команде?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Предположим, у меня есть вот такая команда:

```
add video "user" "videoname"
```

Как мне так спарсить *красиво*, чтобы не париться со *switch*, вызвать нужную мне функцию. То есть как-то определять, что именно я хочу вызвать.

Comment: Похоже Вам нужен DSL (Domain Specific Language). Может Groovy подойдёт для. Покурить мануалы придётся, но такие команды возьмёт. И никаких swith не потребуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Велосипед

Чтобы "не париться со switch" оформите каждое возможное действие в отдельный класс (паттерн проектирования *Command*).

```
public interface Command {
    void execute(List<String> args)
}
```

Возможные команды сложите в `Map<String, Command>`:

```
Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put("add_video", new AddVideoCommand());
```

Разбирайте строку по пробелам. Первый элемент - имя команды, остальные - аргументы. Находите команду по имени и вызывайте:

```
String[] cmdLine = line.split(" ");
if (cmdLine.length == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Command line is empty");
String cmd = cmdLine[0];
List<String> cmdArgs = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(cmdLine, 1, cmdLine.length - 1));
if (commands.containsKey(cmd)) {
    commands.get(cmd).execute(cmdArgs);
}
```

Этого хватит для команд вида `add_video user videoname`. Если вы хотите вложенные команды (`add video ...`, `add user ...`), можно воспользоваться паттерном *Composite*. Композитная команда должна просто содержать таблицу вложенных команд, находить нужную и передавать управление дальше.

```
public class CommandGroup implements Command {
    private final Map<String , Command> subcommands;

    public CommandGroup(Map<String, Command> subcommands) {
        this.subcommands = subcommands;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(List<String> args) {
        if (args.size() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough arguments");

        String subcommand = args.get(0);
        List<String> newArgs = args.subList(1, args.size() - 1);
        if (subcommands.containsKey(subcommand)) {
            subcommands.get(subcommand).execute(newArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь при сборке основной мапы с командами объединяйте вложенные команды вместе при помощи этого класса:

```
Map<String, Command> addCommands = new HashMap<>();
addCommands.put("video", new AddVideoCommand());
addCommands.put("user", new AddUserCommand());

Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put("add", new CommandGroup(addCommands));
```

---

#### Готовое решение

Постепенно ваш командный фреймворк будет усложняться, и возможно вы захотите давать командам имена при помощи аннотаций и объявлять аргументы как параметры метода, находить команды динамически в CLASSPATH, генерировать справку по командам, вызывать команды из команд. В таком случае вам подойдет готовый фреймворк, решающий эти и многие другие проблемы. Например, можно взять [CRaSH](http://www.crashub.org/) и добавление новой команды будет выглядеть на Java так (на Groovy еще лаконичнее):

```
public class add extends BaseCommand {
    @Usage("Adds new video")
    @Command
    public void video(@Usage("user name") @Option(names={"u","user"}) String user,
                      @Usage("video filename") @Option(names={"v","video"}) String video) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо :D

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать с помощью рефлексии.

Вот простой пример:

```
public class Main {

    public int inc(int value) {
        return ++value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        try {

            Method method = Main.class.getMethod("inc", int.class);
            int newValue = (int) method.invoke(main, 1);
            System.out.println(newValue);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Здесь метод `int inc(int value)` вызывается по текстовому представлению его имени.

Аргументы метода `getMethod(...)`: название метода, типы параметров.

Comment: Это я знаю как реализовать. Мне больше интересует, как лучше все это спарсить, чтобы не париться со switch, по каждой командой писать.